# how to use nrow in combine when creating a new column - julia

Tags: julia

I have a dataframe with keywords and a metric. 
So far, I split the keywords, sum the metric to each topic and count the occurence of the topic.
I want to use nrow a second time to create a new metric like "metric_per_frequency". 
Is there a way to do the last part **within** combine? 
(I know it is possible with DataFramesMeta @by but this seemed to be much slower as using combine when testing it on this small sample).
Also I **dont** want this to be done **after** using combine in a new line of code since I seem to be missing the proper usage of combine().

Here is a minimum sample:

```
topics = ["Money,Income,Lifestyle","Knowledge,Windows,Weather","Vaccation,Holiday,Money,Weather"]
metric = [2347820, 1275610, 1255383]

table = DataFrame(topics=topics, metric=metric)

agg_table = combine(
    groupby(
        flatten(transform(table, :topics => ByRow(x -> ismissing(x) ? "" : string.(split(x, ","))) => :topics), :topics),
        [:topics]),
        nrow => :frequency_topics,
        :metric => sum => :sum_metric
        #:metric => sum/nrow .=> :metric_per_frequency
    )
```

The outcome should look like that:

```
Row │ topics     sum_metric  freq_topic  metric_per_frequency
     │ String     Int64       Int64       Float64             
─────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Money         3603203           2              1.8016e6
   2 │ Income        2347820           1              2.34782e
   3 │ Lifestyle     2347820           1              2.34782e
   4 │ Knowledge     1275610           1              1.27561e
   5 │ Windows       1275610           1              1.27561e
   6 │ Weather       2530993           2              1.2655e6
   7 │ Vaccation     1255383           1              1.25538e
   8 │ Holiday       1255383           1              1.25538e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is just `mean` (available after `using Statistics`):

```
julia> agg_table = combine(
           groupby(
               flatten(transform(table, :topics => ByRow(x -> ismissing(x) ? "" : string.(split(x, ","))) => :topics), :topics),
               [:topics]),
               nrow => :frequency_topics,
               :metric => sum => :sum_metric,
               :metric => mean => :metric_per_frequency
           )
8×4 DataFrame
 Row │ topics     frequency_topics  sum_metric  metric_per_frequency
     │ String     Int64             Int64       Float64
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ Money                     2     3603203             1.8016e6
   2 │ Income                    1     2347820             2.34782e6
   3 │ Lifestyle                 1     2347820             2.34782e6
   4 │ Knowledge                 1     1275610             1.27561e6
   5 │ Windows                   1     1275610             1.27561e6
   6 │ Weather                   2     2530993             1.2655e6
   7 │ Vaccation                 1     1255383             1.25538e6
   8 │ Holiday                   1     1255383             1.25538e6
```

Comment: thank you Mr. Kaminski!
That produces the correct table! Why did it not work with nrow ?

Comment: It should be `:metric => (x -> sum(x) / length(x)) => :metric_per_frequency`. You need to use `length` as `nrow` is a property of a data frame as a whole, and here you are working with a single column which has `length` instead.

Comment: exactly what I wanted - thank you very much!